# merging two office files

Tags: 12.04, software-recommendation

How can I take union of two ods according to their column ?

What I want, more specificlly ;

- first compare two ods according to column B
- then merge them
- if there is a intersection, ask me what to do

OR

- compare two ods files
- notify which one has same name, according to column B

Can you recommend me a software, which is available in 12.04, in order to manage one of these wish?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than searching for a GUI tool, you may find it is quicker to export the data to character-delimited files and use the GNU tools for manipulating text files, like :

- `join`
- `sort`
- `diff`

If you are not so inclined but don't mind spending a little money ($30), I find [Beyond Compare 3](http://scootersoftware.com/) to be an excellent merge and compare tool, with a specific mode for data (although you'll still probably have to export to a CSV file).

Disclaimer: I have no financial interest in Scooter Software, I'm merely a happy user of their product on both Windows and Ubuntu.